# Как это работает? Класс с экземплярами классов в качестве аттрибутов

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Нашёл в одной задаче. Совершенно не понимаю концепцию написанного:

```
class User(Model):
    first_name = CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=50)
    email = EmailField()

  
user1 = User(first_name='Liam', last_name='Smith', email='liam@example.com')
```

В задаче написано, что `CharField` и `EmailField`  - это строки. Про `CharField` конкретно написано

```
CharField - a string with min_length (default 0) and max_length (default None) parameters.
```

Я понял только одну вещь, есть экземпляр `user1` класса `User`с аргументами:

```
first_name='Liam', last_name='Smith', email='liam@example.com'
```

Поскольку у `User` нет `__init__` он наследует его у `Model`.

А вот что значат:

```
first_name = CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = CharField(max_length=50)
email = EmailField()
```

Я не понимаю... Это имеет какое-то отношение к метаклассам? Я нигде не могу найти информацию по подобной конструкции и её назначении.

Comment: это похоже на  `Django` .

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin - я пока что с Джанго ещё не знаком, но задача именно так и называется. Я просто не хотел сюда на неё ссылку кидать, чтобы не подумали, что я хочу чтобы за меня её решили) Я просто хочу разобраться с тем, что написано, чтобы решить самому)

Comment: EmailField() по сути тот же `CharField` только со встроеной валидацией для мыла

Comment: Никаких мета-классов https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3 это просто напросто переменные класса, не путать с переменными экземпляра, которые задаются в инит через селф. Работает почти как статические переменные в классах на Java или C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На уровне питона это просто создание атрибутов класса. Т.е. `first_name = CharField(max_length=30)` добавляет в класс `User` атрибут с именем `first_name` и значением типа `CharField` созданным конструктором `CharField` с соответствующими параметрами. Добавляет именно в класс, а не в конкретный экземпляр класса.

Теперь, как эти атрибуты класса используются. В классе `Model` реализован определенный функционал, которы позволяет среди прочего сохранять экземпляры класса в БД, делать запросы к БД используя удобный синтаксис (без SQL) и еще много чего.

Работает это таким образом, что атрибуты класса описывают, какие поля могут храниться экземпляре, их типы, ограничения и т.п.

Конструктор из `Model` работает (упрощенно) так: берет именованные аргументы (в этом примере `first_name='Liam', last_name='Smith', email='liam@example.com'`) и проверяет, что в классе есть атрибуты с соответствующими именами, что типы переданных аргументов совпадают. Далее он сохраняет эти аргументы в полях экземпляра.

Еще в `Model` есть функция `save`, которая позволяет сохранить объект в таблицу БД, которая имеет структуру (т.е. набор полей) такую какая задана атрибутами класса `User`. При этом типы полей соответствуют типам атрибутов в `User`. Для этого `save` строит SQL команду типа `INSERT INTO имя_таблицы (поле1, поле2, ...) values (значение_поля1, ....)`. Именно тут нужно знать список полей их типы и т.д.

Далее `Model` позволяет делать запросы в БД. Например, можно поискать пользователей с заданным именем:

```
users = User.objects.filter(first_name='Bob')
```

Опять же параметры, которые можно передать в `filter` базируются на полях определенных в модели `User`.